# The best way to set rows and headers separately after JTable creation?

Tags: java, swing, header, jtable

It means I need setData and setHeaders functions for JTable

Answer (score 2):

Like Gilbert says, there is no method of the AbstractTableModel that will allow you to set the values of the headers after the JTable is up, since it is not a very common requirement. Still there is a simple work-around to that. I can not say if it is the best way to do it, but it will get you there...

**columnNumber** is the number of the column you want to change and **newHeaderString** is the new String you want to use.

```
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnNumber).setHeaderValue(newHeaderString);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

Since there is a getTableHeader() method, you could call it if you need to further modify your table header properties.

As for setting new data in any row, use jTable1.setValueAt(newObject, row, col);

Answer (score 1):

if you use a `TableModel`, you can change the data contents, but not the column headers.

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
JTable table = new JTable(model)
```

`rowData` and `columnNames` have to be defined before you create the table.

The `TableModel` interface has a `setValueAt` method.  The `TableModel` interface has no method for setting column names.

Comment: omg. You are lucky that I haven't 125 reputation. There is "separately" word in the title. Do you think I haven't read the documentation (especially the info about TableModel and JTable constructors)?